# How to integrate a packaged wysiwyg editor to my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I decided on using [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails), which is a packaged wysiwyg editor with Twitter bootstrap built in.  My question is about how to "activate" the editor inside the form which I created with the `form_for` helper.

I have the following form which I would like to use the wysiwyg editor in:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %> 

  <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :content, "Content" %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %> <!-- make this into wysiwyg editor -->

  <%= f.submit "Create question", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The instructions noted to simply add the following:

```
<textarea id="some-textarea" class='wysihtml5' placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).wysihtml5();
  });
</script>
```

However, I am a bit lost about how I could toggle just my `text_area` section to make it into a wysiwyg.  I looked into the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) for `form_for`, but didn't see how I could insert javascript or even apply a css class to a particular field.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add html class `'wysihtml5'` to any text_area you want to implement the editor on.

```
<%= f.text_area :content, class: 'wysihtml5' %>
```

You can either paste the script inline as suggested, or put a global initializer at `app/assets/javascipts/application.js`:

```
$(function() {
  $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).wysihtml5();
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  This actually seems very easonable too.. will try as soon as I get the chance.